# How to change desktop environments without mixing up their programs?

Tags: gnome, kde, opensuse, desktop-environments

I am relatively new to Linux-based OSes. Well, I tried to install gnome by replacing KDE using YaST (upon selection of gnome, YaST told me that KDE would have to be removed - to which I happily agreed). Now, I expected that all KDE programs would be removed. But when I rebooted, I found that all the KDE programs were still there and that made my PC really messy.

Now, what is the method that **completely** removes a desktop environment and its programs?

One more question. Is there any way to install multiple desktops *in such a way that each environment keeps its programs separately* and I don't end up mixing all programs?

I am using OpenSUSE 13.2 (if that matters).

Comment: The best way would be to freshly install a distro with the desktop enviroment that you want. A good way tp keep programs separate would be to use different users.

Comment: @Fabiusp98 Thanks for the comment but I hardly feel that would be the best way (unless there is no other way).

Answer (score 1):

There is no good automated way of doing this unfortunately this is due to the fact that there are many people out there like me who use some programs from both gnome and kde, Personally I pick my desktop environment based off which one suites my needs best then use each program based off there merit regardless of if they are kde gnome or other. Yes this causes some minor inconsistencies, but if you set them both to use the same theme, or a gnome-kde theme these are only minor.

To answer your question though, there is a way to do this manually, when you install "KDE" or install "gnome" what you really do is install a pattern, all this pattern is, is a list of other programs to install. If you go to the software manager in YAST, and select the Pattern tab, you can see all the programs in the respective patterns and manually uninstall them, in your case probably the KDE4 Base System and KDE4 Desktop environment patterns. You should note though there are programs such as firefox that are neither kde or gnome programs and are probably present in both the KDE and Gnome patterns